# Algebraic proof of complex locus of circle $k|z-z_1|=l|z-z_2|$

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

I am having trouble with this question:

Suppose that

$$k|z-z_{1}|=l|z-z_{2}|$$

where $k\neq l$ and $k,l>0$, $k, l\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that the locus of z in the Argand diagram is a circle with the centre $\frac{k^{2}z_{1}-l^{2}z_{2}}{k^{2}-l^{2}}$ and radius $\frac{kl|z_{2}-z_{1}|}{|k^{2}-l^{2}|}$ by letting $z=x+iy$

I used the identity that a circle with diametrical endpoints $(x_{a}, y_{a})$ and $(x_{b}, y_{b})$ can be written as $$(x-x_{a})(x-x_{b})+(y-y_{a})(y-y_{b})=0$$

Letting $z_{1}=a+ib$ and $z_{2}=u+iv$, the identity gave me $$\left(x-\frac{ak+lu}{k+l}\right)\left(x-\frac{ak-lu}{k-l}\right)+\left(y-\frac{kb+lv}{k+l}\right)\left(y-\frac{kb-lv}{k-l}\right)=0$$

However, I am unsure how to distinguish $x_{a}$ and $x_{b}$, $y_{a}$ and $y_{b}$ (from the identity) in this case i.e I am not sure how to match the real and imaginary parts of the diametrical endpoints. I guessed correctly that the real and imaginary parts had the same denominators, but why is this the case? This method also involved extremely heavy algebra, is there a way to do it that is shorter and doesn't use the identity?

Comment: The locus of points with constant ratio between distances to two fixed points is a circle, whose center and radius are fairly easy to derive geometrically. Lookup the [circles of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles).

Comment: Yes, but the question specifically asks by letting $z=x+iy$ :(

Comment: I read that more as a hint than a requirement. What you are asked to prove is essentially $\left| z - \frac{k^{2}z_{1}-l^{2}z_{2}}{k^{2}-l^{2}} \right| = \frac{kl|z_{2}-z_{1}|}{|k^{2}-l^{2}|}\,$. For a geometrically-less approach, you could try and adapt [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2091243/291201).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the given, $k^2|z-z_1|^2=l^2|z-z_2|^2$, or

$$k^2(z-z_1)(\bar z -\bar z_1) =l^2 (z-z_2)(\bar z -\bar z_2)
$$

Regroup the terms

$$|z|^2 - \frac{k^2\bar z_1 - l^2\bar z_2}{ k^2-l^2 }z - \frac{k^2z_1 - l^2z_2}{ k^2-l^2}\bar z = \frac{l^2|z_2|^2-k^2|z_1|^2}{ k^2-l^2}
$$

or, in the familiar form

$$|z- \frac{k^2z_1 - l^2z_2}{ k^2-l^2}|^2=  \frac{k^2l^2|z_1-z_2|^2}{( k^2-l^2)^2}
$$

Thus, the locus is a circle with the center $\frac{k^2z_1 - l^2z_2}{ k^2-l^2}$ and the radius $ \frac{kl|z_1-z_2|}{|k^2-l^2|}$.

Comment: But how did you get from the 3rd equation to the 4th equation? Are you completing the square of the $z$ coefficient? How does the conjugate disappear?