# How can one sketch a complex inequality with absolute values on both sides?

Tags: complex-numbers

How can one sketch such an inequality on the complex plane?

$$|z+4+3i| \leq |5z +10 -9i|$$

I tried to simplify the inequality and got to

$$-39 \leq 6x^2+23x+6y^2-24y$$

How can I proceed further? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Thank you very much for your help.

[Here is the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mOBh.jpg)

Comment: Complete the square (for $x$ and then for $y$), and you've you an inequality for either inside or outside a circle.

Comment: How can I interpret then the inequality to represent it? Very roughly I come to $-7≤(x+2)^2 + (y-2)^2$

Comment: Hint: the equality case is the locus of points with constant ratio between distances to two fixed points, which is an Apollonian circle - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137544/algebraic-proof-of-complex-locus-of-circle-kz-z-1-lz-z-2) for example.

Comment: An equation such as [$\dfrac{|z-z_A|}{|z-z_B|}=k\iff\dfrac{MA}{MB}=k$] (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085237/399263)  is always circle unless it is degenerated into the perpendicular bisector when $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct. You now have to rewrite the inequality in the form:

$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\ge r^2\;.$$

You will find:

$$x_0=-\frac{23}{12}$$

$$y_0=2$$

$$r=\frac{13}{12}\;.$$

Therefore, the region that satisfies the inequality is the part of the complex plane external ($\gt$) to the circle centred at $(x_0,y_0)$ of radius $r$ plus the circle itself ($=$).

Comment: To find the coordinates of the centre of the circle you have to look at the coefficients of the terms with $x$ and $y$ (remember $(x-x_0)^2=x^2+x_0^2-2x_0x$). You then subtract the additional terms $x_0^2+y_0^2$ you have introduced to find the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Write this as
$|z+4+3i| \leq 5|z +2 -\frac95i|
$
or
$|z-(-4-3i)| \leq 5|z -(-2+\frac95i)|
$.

This says that
the distance to
$-4-3i$
is less than or equal to
$5$ times the distance
to
$-2+\frac95 i$.

Both of those regions are circles,
one with radius $1$
and one with radius $5$.

Draw the two circles
and see how they are related.

Answer (score 0):

$6x^2 + 23x + 6y^2 + 24y \ge -39$

We could complete the square, and see that this describes the plane outside of some disk.

And once we know that $|z - \omega_1| = a|z - \omega_2|$ describes a circle.  And the inequality the area inside and outside, we can skip the algebra cut to the chase in sketching it.

We know the circle cuts the line segment between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ at a ratio of $1:a$  and a point on the extension of the line of $\omega_1$ again preserving ratios of distance.  The mid-point will be the center of the circle.