# How do i find $z$ with $|z+9|=3|z+1|$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, circles, absolute-value

When z is a complex number, how do I find $z$ with $|z+9|=3|z+1|$?
I tried replacing $z$ with $x + yi$ but I'm stuck with all of them under the square root.

Comment: Then square both sides to eliminate the square roots.

Comment: He means it when $z$ is a complex number, misuse of a question mark.

Comment: @DougM I reworded it as an edit now, I think he means what I fixed in the edit.

Comment: @YashJain oh, I knew exactly what the OP meant.  I was just trying to give a small nudge how solve his problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can do this entirely without splitting $z$ into $x+iy$.  We have
$$\eqalign{|z+9|=3|z+1|\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad |z+9|^2=9|z+1|^2\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad (z+9)(\overline z+9)=9(z+1)(\overline z+1)\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad \cdots\quad
      \hbox{(a bit of easy algebra, leave it up to you)}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad z\overline z=9\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad |z|=3\cr}$$
which is a circle with centre $0$, radius $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+yi,$ where $\{x,y\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Thus, we have $$\sqrt{(x+9)^2+y^2}=3\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$ or $$(x+9)^2+y^2=9((x+1)^2+y^2),$$ which gives an equation of the  circle
$$x^2+y^2=9.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  the locus of points in the plane with constant ratio $\,\left|\dfrac{z+9}{z+1}\right| = 3\,$ between the distances to the two fixed points $\,-9, -1\,$ is a [circle of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius.27_definition_of_a_circle) having as diameter the points that divide the segment between $\,-9\,$ and $\,-1\,$ in ratio $\,3:1\,$ internally and respectively externally. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2091243/291201) for the complete derivation.