# Solving $|z-4i|=2|z+4|$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

$$\begin{align}
|z-4i|&=2|z+4|\\[4pt]
|x+yi-4i|&=2|x+yi+4|\\[4pt]
|x+i(y-4)|&=2|(x+4)+iy|\\[4pt]
\sqrt{x^2+(y-4)^2}&=2\sqrt{(x+4)^2+y^2}\\[4pt]
(\sqrt{x^2+(y-4)^2})^2&=(2\sqrt{(x+4)^2+y^2})^2\\[4pt]
x^2+y^2-8y+16&= 4(x^2+8x+16+y^2)\\[4pt]
x^2+y^2-8y+16&= 4x^2+32x+64+4y^2\\[4pt]
0&= 3x^2+3y^2+32x+8y+48
\end{align}$$

Is it okay? Thank you

Comment: Other than the fact that you should have put some $\iff$ signs in your answer, it looks fine.

Comment: @tina_98 Yes,absolutely correct.

Comment: I suggest you use the command `align` when listing equations like you do. Also, do not type things like '\$x+y\$=\$3\$', just write '\$x+y=3\$' instead. I am not editing your question on purpose, so that you can learn these simple commands trying them directly. About the content: the steps look good --- even if in the second to last line it is $4y^2$ on the right hand side --- but then I would add that the solutions are those complex numbers $z = x+iy$ such that $3x^2+3y^2+32x+8y+48=0$.

Comment: @tina_98 Depending on what the problem was specifically asking for, you may need an extra step at the end to recognize that the last equation represents a circle. It is in fact a [circle of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius.27_definition_of_a_circle), see the similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2620101/291201) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2090970/291201).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computation is fine.

But I’ve been meditating on the form of your final result, since it says that the locus is a circle: coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are the same, and no $xy$ term. So there must be a theorem from plane geometry that says: *If $P$ and $Q$ are points in the plane, the locus of points $R$ that are $k$ times as far from $Q$ as from $P$ is a circle, if $k\ne1$.*

It’s easy enough to prove this analytically, by a method the same as yours, but surely there has to be a synthetic proof, perhaps even straight out of Euclid.

Does anyone know such a proof? Or can you cook one up? I looked at it, and have been stumped so far.

Anyway, thanks for a provocative question (and calculation).

Comment: I see that the comment of @dxiv above covers the question exhaustively.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach altogether:

$$\begin{align}
|z-4i|=2|z+4|
&\iff\left|z-4i\over z+4 \right|=2\\
&\iff{z-4i\over z+4 }=2e^{i\theta}\quad\text{for some }\theta\in\mathbb{R}\\
&\iff z={8e^{i\theta}+4i\over1-2e^{i\theta}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: And finally you have to write $z$ in Cartesian form with parameter $\theta$ to see its locus is a circle.

Comment: @Bumblebee, agreed. Or else cite a theorem that says that linear fractional transformations take circles to circles. It's partly a question of what you can take as known. It also depends on what it means to "solve" the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is completely fine. Continue it with:
$$x^2+\frac{32}{3}x+y^2+\frac 83 y+16=0$$
Now complete the square on the $x$'s and $y$'s
$$(x+\frac{16}{3})^2-\frac{256}{9}+(y+\frac43)^2-\frac{16}{9}+16=0$$

$$(x+\frac{16}{3})^2+(y+\frac{4}{3})^2=\frac{128}{9}$$
Thus we have a circle, centre $(-\frac{16}{3}, -\frac 43)$, radius $\frac{8\sqrt2}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

So far so good.

You may continue to see the geometry of the solution as well.

$$3x^2+3y^2+32x+8y+48=0$$

$$x^2+y^2+(32/3)x+(8/3)y+16=0$$

Which is the equation of a circle.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, it is just a typo and the rest of the work is good.

Comment: I would recommend a few more lines: $3x^2+ 3y^2+ 32x+ 8y+ 48= 3(x^2+ (32/3)x+ y^2+ (8/3)y+ 48/3= 0$

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani you ought to get it into the correct form: $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$

Comment: @Rhys good idea and you have it right . (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine, but you should realize that it is an equation for the  circle with center $\left(-\dfrac{16}{3},-\dfrac{4}{3}\right)$ and with radius $\dfrac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}$.  If I were your grader, I would not give you a full credit for simply finding the final equation, yet not realizing it gives a circle.  Here is an alternative solution, using Euclidean geometry of the plane.

Let $A$ denote the point $4\text{i}$ of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$, whilst $B$ is the point $-4$.  Thus, if the point $C$ with complex coordinate $z$ satisfies
$$|z-4\text{i}|=2\,|z+4|\,,$$
then
$$CA=2\,CB\,.$$
On the line $AB$, there are two solutions $D$ and $E$, with complex coordinates
$$\frac{1}{3}\,(4\text{i})+\frac{2}{3}\,(-4)=\frac{-8+4\text{i}}{3}\text{ and }(-1)\,(4\text{i})+2\,(-4)=-8-4\text{i}\,,$$
respectively.  Thus, the point $C$ is a point such that $CD$ is the internal angular bisector of $\angle ACB$ and $CE$ is the external angular bisector of $\angle ACB$.  We can easily [show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Circle_of_Apollonius) that the locus of $C$ is a circle $\Gamma$ with diameter $DE$.

Thus, the center $P$ of $\Gamma$ has the complex coordinate
$$\frac{1}{2}\,\left(\frac{-8+4\text{i}}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\,(-8-4\text{i})=\frac{-16-4\text{i}}{3}\,.$$
The radius of $\Gamma$ is $$\frac{1}{2}\,\Biggl|\left(\frac{-8+4\text{i}}{3}\right)-(-8-4\text{i})\Biggr|=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}\,.$$
In other words, the complex coordinate $z$ of $C$ satisfies
$$\Biggl|z-\left(\frac{-16-4\text{i}}{3}\right)\Biggr|=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}\,.$$
We can also write
$$z=\left(\frac{-16-4\text{i}}{3}\right)+\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}\,\exp(\text{i}\theta)\,,$$
where $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

In general, any solution $z\in\mathbb{C}$ to $|z-a|=r\,|z-b|$, where $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\setminus\{1\}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ is given by the circle
$$\left|z-c\right|=\rho\,.$$
Here, $c:=\dfrac{-a+r^2b}{r^2-1}$ and $\rho:=\dfrac{r}{|r^2-1|}\,|a-b|$.  In other words,
$$z=c+\rho\,\exp(\text{i}\theta)\,,$$
where $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.  (Note that the solutions in the case where $r=1$ form a degenerate circle---a straight line.  This straight line is the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining $a$ and $b$.  It is given by the equation $(a-b)\,\bar{z}+(\bar{a}-\bar{b})z=|a|^2-|b|^2$, or equivalently, $\text{Re}\big((\bar{a}-\bar{b})\,z\big)=\dfrac{|a|^2-|b|^2}{2}$.  In other words, $z=\dfrac{a+b}{2}+\text{i}(a-b)\,t$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the set of points
which are twice as far from
$-4$ as from $4i$.

I'll work out
the case of arbitrary points
and ratio of distances.

If the points are
$(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$
and the ratio is $r$,
then
$|z-(a, b)| = r|z-(c, d)|$
or,
if $z = (x, y)$,
$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}
=r\sqrt{(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2}
$.

Squaring and expanding,
$x^2-2ax+a^2+y^2-2by+b^2
=r^2(x^2-2cx+c^2+y^2-2dy+d^2)
$.

Grouping,
$x^2(r^2-1)+2(a-r^2c)x+y^2(r^2-1)+2(b-r^2d)y
+r^2(c^2+d^2)-a^2-b^2
=0
$.

If $r=1$,
this becomes
$2(a-c)x+2(b-d)y
+c^2+d^2-a^2-b^2
=0
$,
which is the
equation of a straight line.
This is because the set of points
equidistant from two points
is the perpendicular bisector
of the line joining
the two points.

If $r \ne 1$,
this is of the form
$Ax^2+Bx+Ay^2+Cy+D
=0
$
which is the equation
of a circle.
To see this,
write this as

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=Ax^2+Bx+Ay^2+Cy+D\\
&=A\left(x^2+(B/A)x+y^2+(C/A)y+D/A\right)\\
&=A\left(x^2+(B/A)x+(B^2/4A^2)-(B^2/4A^2)+y^2+(C/A)y+(C^2/4A^2)-(C^2/4A^2)+D/A\right)\\
&=A\left((x+B/2A)^2+(y+C/2A)^2+D/A-(B^2/4A^2)-(C^2/4A^2)\right)\\
&=A\left((x+B/2A)^2+(y+C/2A)^2+(4AD-B^2-C^2)/(4A^2)\right)\\
\end{array}
$

or
$(x+B/2A)^2+(y+C/2A)^2
=(B^2+C^2-4AD)/(4A^2)
$.

This is a circle
with center at
$-B/2A, -C/2A)$
and radius
$\sqrt{B^2+C^2-4AD}/(2A)
$.
For the circle to have a
real radius,
we must have
$B^2+C^2-4AD
\ge 0$.

In our case,

$\begin{array}\\
B^2+C^2-4AD
&=(2(a-r^2c))^2+(2(b-r^2d))^2-4(r^2-1)(r^2(c^2+d^2)-a^2-b^2)\\
&=4\left(a^2-2r^2ac+r^4c^2+b^2-2r^2bd+r^4d^2-(r^2-1)r^2(c^2+d^2)+(r^2-1)(a^2+b^2)\right)\\
&=4\left((a^2+b^2)(1+(r^2-1))+(c^2+d^2)(1-r^2(r^2-1))-2ac-2bd)\right)\\
&=4\left(r^2(a^2+b^2)+(c^2+d^2)(r^4-r^2(r^2-1))-2r^2(ac+bd)\right)\\
&=4\left(r^2(a^2+b^2)+r^2(c^2+d^2)-2r^2(ac+bd)\right)\\
&=4r^2\left((a^2+b^2)+(c^2+d^2)-2(ac+bd)\right)\\
&=4r^2\left((a^2-2ac+c^2)+(b^2-2bd+d^2)\right)\\
&=4r^2\left((a-c)^2+(b-d)^2)\right)\\
&\ge 0\\
\end{array}
$

The radius is zero
if and only if
$a=c$ and $b=d$,
which means the two points
are the same.

Otherwise the radius is
$\dfrac{2r\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}}{2(r^2-1)}
=\dfrac{r\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}}{r^2-1}
$.

The center is at
$
(-\dfrac{a-r^2c}{r^2-1},
-\dfrac{b-r^2d}{r^2-1})
=(\dfrac{r^2c-a}{r^2-1},
\dfrac{r^2d-b}{r^2-1})
=\dfrac{1}{r^2-1}(r^2(c, d)-(a, b))
$.

Note that if
$r=0$
then the center is at
$(a, b)$
and the radius is
zero,
so the circle is a point
at $(a, b)$.

Similarly,
if
$r\to \infty$,
then the center goes to
$(c, d)$
and the radius goes to
zero,
so the circle again is a point.