# Complex Analysis: Locus of $z$ satisfying $|z-4|=4|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, locus

Just want to know if I'm on the right track here.

let $z=iy$
$|z-4| = 4|z|$
$\Rightarrow \sqrt{(x-4)^2 +y^2} = 4\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
$\Rightarrow (x-4)^2 +y^2 = 16x^2 + 16y^2$
$\Rightarrow x^2 -8x -16 -16x^2 = 15y^2$
$\Rightarrow -x^2 -\frac{8}{15}x -\frac{16}{15}  = y^2$
$\Rightarrow \pm \sqrt{-x^2 -\frac{8}{15}x -\frac{16}{15}  }= y$

Is the locus the set of points on the boundary of this closed shape on the plane? I think I could have used polar co-ordinates here, but is my intuition correct?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891300/solving-z-4i-2z4.  From some answers there, you would see that the solution set is the circle centered at the point with complex coordinates $\dfrac{-4+4^2\cdot 0}{4^2-1}=-\dfrac{4}{15}$ and with radius $\dfrac{4}{4^2-1}\,|4-0|=\dfrac{16}{15}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2 +\frac{8}{15}x -\frac{16}{15} + y^2=0$$

this is an equation of a circle:

$$ (x+{4\over 15})^2+y^2 = {16\over 225}+{16\over 15}$$